# Android SDK Tools option is missing from SDK Manager in Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, macos-catalina, android-studio-3.6

On a freshly installed macOS Catalina, I installed Android Studio 3.6.1.

I've got the following error when I ran `flutter doctor` in the course of setting up flutter SDK on my Mac.

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
        Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
        See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
        https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I re-installed Android Studio and follow the instructions in the second link in the error message, but these links do not seem to help resolving the issue. I also tried the following:

```
$ flutter doctor  --android-licenses
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Android sdkmanager tool not found
(/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I checked my installation and found out that `tools` directory is missing under `~/Library/Android/sdk/`.

Also, I found out `Android SDK Tools` option is missing from SDK Tools tab in SDK Manager of the Android Studio [as shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJvCb.png). (`Android SDK Tools` option was present on my previous installation of Android Studio 3.5.3.)

Has anyone had the similar problem? I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can show me how I can fix this issue, I'd appreciate it! (This is my first question on Stack Overflow. Please excuse me for lengthy post.)

Comment: Seriously, they want every time their developers spend hours in doing R&D just to get little things done after their new release.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using Linux but I guess the problem might be the same.

Launch Android Studio and go to "SDK Manager" - you can launch it after creating a blank project and going "Tools -> SDK Manager" under the "AVD Manager" option. In the new window open "System Settings -> Android SDK". From there pick "SDK Tools". Now you need to uncheck the "Hide Obsolete Packages" option in the bottom of the window. Now there should appear a new option: "Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)" - check that, hit "Apply" - it will download the files and "Tools" folder will appear in the Android folder. Then simply run "flutter doctor" in the terminal and you should be asked to accept some licenses - simply run:

```
$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

It helped me. I don't know why this option went obsolete when Flutter requires it anyway. Check the settings printscreen.

[image]

Comment: Unchecking `Hide Obsolete Packages` solved the issue. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

Step1. Download latest sdk tools from https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/SDKTools.(changed https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/sdk_tools.html)
up to 2020-03-08 the latest version is 26.2.0.

Step2. Unzip and then copy "tools" folder into android-sdk folder. "tools" and "build-tools" is in the same depth.

Step3. flutter doctor --android-licenses

Step4. flutter doctor

Comment: I wonder why this URL is not documented anywhere on the Android Studio download page; it would have saved me so much time! Thank you for that!

Comment: Above link is not working anymore.

Comment: changed https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/sdk_tools.html    @RochaaP

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Android Studio SDK Manager
2. In the Android SDK tab, uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages
3. Check Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) Check and download it!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Android Studio 3.6.1 (not involving flutter): the `platform-tools` directory got installed within another `platform-tools` directory, so Android Studio couldn't find `adb`, and so couldn't communicate with my phone. A completely fresh re-install of Android Studio didn't even help. I ended up manually moving the `platform-tools` one directory up and that fixed it:

```
% cd ~/Library/Android/sdk
% mv platform-tools platform-tools-bad
% mv platform-tools-bad/platform-tools .
```