# Android Studio 3.6, Cordova, Win 10

Tags: cordova

I've followed the Cordova docs and various troubleshooting methods, but 'cordova requirements" always errors on:

Android target: not installed

Android Studio 3.6 does not install a /tools/ directory, which I think Cordova may be looking for.

Does anyone have a working install guide for the latest Android Studio and Cordova on Windows 10? Is Cordova only usuable with certain Studio versions?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the /tools/ folder is the problem, in Android Studio 3.6 the SDK Tools are obsolete and not installed by default. I found the way to manually install here:

[Android SDK Tools option is missing from SDK Manager in Android Studio 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467477/android-sdk-tools-option-is-missing-from-sdk-manager-in-android-studio-3-6-1)

"Launch Android Studio and go to "SDK Manager" - you can launch it after creating a blank project and going "Tools -> SDK Manager" under the "AVD Manager" option. In the new window open "System Settings -> Android SDK". From there pick "SDK Tools". Now you need to uncheck the "Hide Obsolete Packages" option in the bottom of the window. Now there should appear a new option: "Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)" - check that, hit "Apply" - it will download the files and "Tools" folder will appear in the Android folder."

Ironically, Google's own Flutter development tools also depend on the SDK Tools that they have made obsolete.