# Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm trying to use flutter on Android Studio. I have the flutter plugin installed on Android Studio and when i try to create a new flutter project it behaves normally, in the sense of it lets me write the project name, the flutter sdk path and so on. But when i click on finish absolutely nothing happens. I just see the Android Studio Welcome page where i can create new Projects. So i figured I'd see what flutter doctor -v has to say about it and it gives me these errors:
[image: Here you can see the errors i get]

So i try to find a solution by typing : flutter doctor --android-licenses but i get another error:
[image: The error in red]

And yes i have set the PATH variable and i have installed Android SDK Tools.

I tried everything but nothing seems to do the job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Give a look to this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60468907/7316824) it might help you.**

Comment: I tried doing that but the problem is still the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Install Android Studio Latest Version Your Problem will be solved

Answer (score -1):

if you are using windows OS, backup your data, reinstall windows..remember to choose option  to keep your files and application..after finish..check updates and update windows..
then run flutter doctor --android-licenses